# Cant connect to URL in java to copy raw JSON text

Tags: java, android, json

I'm writing a android trivia app that uses the Open Trivia DB to generate its questions. The problem I'm incurring is that I'm simply unable to connect to the generated API url and I'm not sure why.

I'm simply trying to pull the raw text from the URL and then sort it later, here is the relevant code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    try {
        getJSON();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Log.d("CREATION","Something wrong");
    }
}




private String getJSON()throws IOException{
    URL trivia = new URL("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10");
    URLConnection yc = trivia.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        Log.d("CREATION",inputLine);
    in.close();
    return "";
}
}
```

The Stack trace from the errors I get comes back with this:

```
 at edu.niu.students.z1802067.triviaapp.MainActivity.getJSON(MainActivity.java:59)
```

which is this line of code:

```
      yc.getInputStream()));
```

How could I write this to simply get all the raw text from the JSON?

Comment: What kind of exception do you receive in the stack trace above the line you shared?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you try make request with UI thread. It's blocking UI for a long time (time of request)

Try use thread like this:

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            getJSON();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("CREATION","Something wrong: " + e, e);
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Better solution for reading data form API is use library like https://square.github.io/retrofit/ 
It simplifies the task and data processing